# Check if column exists for one table in DB

Tags: database, columns

In my addon, I would like to check on activation, if a column of a specific table in the DB already exists to avoid to implement it for each activation.

Something like this :

```
class MainClassAddon{

     public function __construct(){
         register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'install' ) );
     }

     public function install(){

         if( /*Checking if column c in table wp_t exists*/ ){
             $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_t ADD c INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1");
         }
     }
}
new MainClassAddon();
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__,  array( 'PluginNamespace\MainClassAddon', 'uninstall' ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330932/add-new-column-to-wordpress-database#answer-21331762)

So...

```
class MainClassAddon{

     public function __construct(){
         register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'install' ) );
     }

     public function install(){

         $row = $wpdb->get_results(  "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'wp_t' AND column_name = 'c'"  );

         if(empty($row)){
             $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_t ADD c INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1");
         }
     }
}
new MainClassAddon();
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__,  array( 'PluginNamespace\MainClassAddon', 'uninstall' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a built-in function for this: **maybe_add_column()** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_add_column/

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wp_t';
$column_name = 'c';
$create_ddl = "ALTER TABLE $table_name ADD $column_name INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
maybe_add_column($table_name, $column_name, $create_ddl);
```

Applying it to your solution:

```
class MainClassAddon{

     public function __construct(){
         register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'install' ) );
     }

     public function install(){
         global $wpdb;
         $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wp_t';
         $column_name = 'c';
         $create_ddl = "ALTER TABLE $table_name ADD $column_name INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;";
    
         require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
         maybe_add_column($table_name, $column_name, $create_ddl);
     }
}
new MainClassAddon();
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__,  array( 'PluginNamespace\MainClassAddon', 'uninstall' ) );
```